# how are custom object permissions set for standard profiles?

Tags: force.com, profile

I'm looking at the std profile, contract manager, and for some custom objects in our org, they have CRUD privileges for a bunch of objects and no access whatsoever to a bunch more. What drives the privileges to be set this way when it comes to standard profiles?

EDIT- oddly, enough I checked all 6 STD profiles and  4 of them had the same CRUD access to the same custom objects. Read-only could only read those same objects...

I suspect there maybe a historical thing going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Standard Profiles](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/standard_profiles.htm) come default with set [User Permissions](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_userperms.htm). User Profiles and their customizations are set [based on the org type](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_userprofiles.htm):

> In Contact Manager, Group, and Professional Edition organizations, you
>   can assign standard profiles to your users, but you can't view or edit
>   the standard profiles or create custom profiles. In Enterprise,
>   Unlimited, and Developer Edition organizations, you can use standard
>   profiles, or create, edit, and delete custom profiles. For standard
>   profiles, only certain settings can be changed.
>
> Each standard or custom profile belongs to exactly one user license
>   type.

---

Essentially, these profiles are set up and only some of them allow certain functionality. Not all of the profiles allow access to certain objects (specifically, [profiles associated to Portals](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customer_portal_manage_users.htm#CPprofiles) are very restrictive). This is just how the profiles are set up.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to assign users standard profiles and then "customise" them is to clone those profiles, typically as `Custom: Standard Profile Name`, after which you will have full control over the profile settings.

I suspect (as you mentioned) that standard profiles are hard-baked into the platform due to some historical architecture decision.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what's been said above and to provide some documentation that further validates it, from p.140 - 141 of the [Force.com Fundamentals Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf), also sometimes referred to by some as the "Creating on Demand Apps pdf":

> **Standard Profiles**
>
> The platform provides the following set of standard profiles in every organization:
>
> • Read Only
>
> • Standard User
>
> • Marketing User
>
> • Contract Manager
>
> • Solution Manager
>
> • System Administrator
>
> Each of these standard profiles includes a default set of permissions for all of the
> standard objects available on the platform.
>
> When a custom object is created, most profiles (except those with “Modify All Data”) don't
> give access to the object. You can find more detailed descriptions of all the standard profiles
> in the online help, but the important thing to know is that **you can never edit the object
> permissions on a standard profile.** If you have access to the Enterprise, Unlimited, or Developer
> Editions of the platform, it’s a good idea to make copies of the standard profiles and then
> customize the copies to fit the needs of your organization.