# Add users to an app

Tags: app, user

UPDATE:

Sorry if my question seems slightly "beginner" as I'm one.

So I created an app on salesforce.  Of course I populated my objects with data to see if what I developed worked the way I wanted to.

Now I would like people in my company to be able to use that app.

How do we do that?

Create a user?  Done
Create a permission set for that app and assign it to that user?  Done

Question 1> Is it normal that when I log in with this newly created user, I can't see any of the data I've inputted as a developer?
Question 2> We are a small cie (need 3 users), and we only need that app that I've created (noe of the other CRM stuff), what license do you thing we should buy?  platform?

Thanks for your advices.

**WHY can't I check any of the boxes in Custom Object Permissions in my user profile edit?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the app usage check the following:

1. Check the security settings of the objects that you populated.  Under the setup menu, go to Security Controls | Sharing Settings.  That will take you to a screen that shows [Organization Wide Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en_US).  If your Object's Default Access is set to Private then only the user that created the record will be able to see it and if the Grant Access Using Hierarchies is checked then those above it in the role hierarchy will be able to see the record as well.  In your small organization, if you don't have any reason to not share the records then you can just set the Default Access to Public Read/Write.
2. Make sure that their profile or permission set has the app assigned to it, the correct Object and Field Level Security permissions, and that the tabs are set to Default On.

If you don't need access to anything but the core CRM Objects and functionality (e.g., [access to Accounts and Contacts, but not Opportunities](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000186561&language=en_US)), your custom objects, and your custom app then the platform license is the correct one to look at using.

Comment: Hi Peter,   Again thanks for your help.  In the Organization-Wide Defaults, all the objects of my app are on Public read/write.  Except a few where it is said "controlled by parents".

Comment: My user has is a Standard Platform User.  So I go on Profile Edit, and make sure that on Custom App Settings, my app is selected.  Same thing with Custom tab setting.   BUT then on Custom Object Permissions, I'm not allowed to select any of the checkboxes?  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

OK I guess the trick was to make a clone of the standard user profile, then edit that clone. This is because we can't customized the created objects on the original standard user profile.

see:

[how are custom object permissions set for standard profiles?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10720/how-are-custom-object-permissions-set-for-standard-profiles)